# Could not find System.Object VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, fody, fody-costura

> Error : Fody: Could not find 'System.Object'. WindowsApp1

hi, something called Fody, it embed dlls assembly into project.

problem is it work only with C# |and i need use it as VB, i cant reduce Netframwork less than 4.6 cause dll's required high netframwork.

error only occurs when running Fody on a VB assembly using the full .Net Framework

[image: the tested result]

so they say it can be solve By

try adding explicit references to your VB project

```
<Reference Include="mscorlib" />
<Reference Include="System" />
```

how can do it, because not automatically included in VB projects

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Go to your Project file
- edit vbproj
- you can find `<Reference Include="System" />`
- add before it `<Reference Include="mscorlib" />`

Comment: is there a CLI way to do this?

Comment: @bilogic , IDK for real, but this the simple way that can fix the issue currently time.